# Yii accessing relational data from Yii::app->user

Tags: php, yii

**I would like to know whether it is possible or if there is a easier way to do this.**

On many pages i'd like to use the relational data, now every page i use it i place the following code:

```
<?php
    if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest){
        $user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    }
?>
```

So I can use the following in the view:

```
$user->account->name
```

To display current users related account's name

It would be nice if I could just do the following:

```
Yii::app->user->account->name
```

Set state isn't what i'm looking for since it's not only the account name i want to use, and I don't want to add a state for all relational data I might want to use.

```
 Solution

 |
 |
 |
 V
```

**Solution**

I combined the good of both answers to create the following:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
private $_user;

public function getAccount(){
    if(!$this->isGuest && (!isset($this->_user) || Yii::app()->user->id != $this->_user->id)){
        $this->_user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    }
    if(!empty($this->_user)){
        return $this->_user->account;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

  }
}
```

So now I can use the following:

```
Yii::app()->user->account->name
```

The above method retrieves the data if the user is logged in and there is no data stored or the user has a different id.

Place it in Components and be sure to add the part Afnan talks about to the config (main.php)

*I accept the answer of Afnan because it helped me most (The part I needed to know)*

Comment: pls, fix return $this->_user->account;   to   return $this->_user;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well i do not know if it is the best solution but i usually do things like this by extending `CWebUser`

What i would do is create file in Components folder that extends `CWebUser`

```
class CWebUserExtend extends CWebUser
{
    /**
     *
     * @return the type of user based on forien key of UserType
     */
    public function getUserAccname()
    {
        $user = User::model()->findByPk(yii::app()->user->id);
        if ($user === null)
            return 'error';            
        else
            return $user->account->name;            
    }
}
```

and in main.php file modify 'User' index in following manner

```
'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                        'class'=>'CWebUserExtend',//class that extends CWebUser
        ),
```

This would allow you to do something

```
Yii::app()->user->getUserAccname();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Similar to Afnan's answer, but just my 2 cents. I extend the webuser class like Afnan suggests but also have an `account` model which I use for the database access and model rules. I access this by having a function on my `ExWebUser` class:

```
public function getAccount(){
    return Account::model()->findByPk($this->id);
}
```

This allows me to access it with `Yii::app()->user->account->name` which feels much cleaner than having a method per action if you have a lot of things to do.

*P.S*
This can obviously be much improved by caching the result in a private variable on the extended class and possibly pre-loading on the `init()` method.

Comment: Preloading in Init isn't possible in this scenario since upon init there is no user logged in, and I needed the relational data of the logged in user.

Thnx for your answer anyhow, i think my current solution is quite neat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help ! I just noticed that i had to change your code to :

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {
private $_user;

public function getAccount(){
    if(!$this->isGuest && (!isset($this->_user) || Yii::app()->user->id != $this->_user->id)){
        $this->_user = User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->id);
    }
    if(!empty($this->_user)){
        return $this->_user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

  }
}
```

I only return `$this->_user` to access my User's attributes like `Yii::app()->user->account->name`

Comment: By changing the function name to getInfo() you should be able to use 
Yii::app()->user->info->name

In case you dislike using "account".